# how to store a Ruby array into a file?

Tags: ruby

How to store a Ruby array into a file?

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you asking how to define an array as part of ruby source code, or how to serialize an array on the disk  ?

Comment: I am talking about the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to dump an array to disk. You need to decide if you want to serialize in a binary format or in a text format.

For binary serialization you can look at [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html)

For text format you can use [json](http://flori.github.com/json/), [yaml](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html), xml (with [rexml](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/), [builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/), ... ) , ...

Answer (score 18):

I am not sure what exactly you want, but, to serialize an array, write it to a file and read back, you can use this:

```
fruits = %w{mango banana apple guava}
=> ["mango", "banana", "apple", "guava"]
serialized_array = Marshal.dump(fruits)
=> "\004\b[\t\"\nmango\"\vbanana\"\napple\"\nguava"
File.open('/tmp/fruits_file.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write(serialized_array) }
=> 33
# read the file back
fruits = Marshal.load File.read('/tmp/fruits_file.txt')
=> ["mango", "banana", "apple", "guava"]
```

There are other alternatives you can explore, like `json` and `YAML`.

Answer (score 8):

To just dump the array to a file in the standard [a,b,c] format:

```
require 'pp'
$stdout = File.open('path/to/file.txt', 'w')
pp myArray
```

That might not be so helpful, perhaps you might want to read it back? In that case you could use [json](http://flori.github.com/json/). Install using rubygems with `gem install json`.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
$stdout = File.open('path/to/file.txt', 'w')
puts myArray.to_json
```

Read it back:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
buffer = File.open('path/to/file.txt', 'r').read
myArray = JSON.parse(buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some standard options for serializing data in Ruby:

- [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html)
- [YAML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/YAML.html)
- [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/JSON.html) (built-in as of 1.9, various gems available as well)

(There are other, arguably better/faster implementations of YAML and JSON, but I'm linking to built-ins for a start.)

In practice, I seem to see YAML most often, but that may not be indicative of anything real.

Comment: nice, I didn't know JSON was built into ruby 1.9 now

Comment: @ghoppe - yeah, I should mention that in an edit. I actually prefer to use yajl-json - it's speedy - but I didn't want to clutter the answer.

Comment: I believe they did some work to make YAML be a superset of JSON.  You might be able to parse JSON with a YAML parser when using Ruby 1.8.

Comment: @Benjamin Oakes: that's true as of YAML 1.2. However, the builtin YAML parser/emitter in Ruby 1.8 and 1.9.1 is based on an older version of the specification which is not a proper superset of JSON. Even worse: it's not even spec-compliant. This only changes in Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Really?  That's good to know.  I've only used YAML for somewhat simple stuff, so I haven't run into the spec problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick yaml example

```
config = {"rank" => "Admiral", "name"=>"Akbar",
          "wallet_value" => 9, "bills" => [5,1,1,2]}

open('store.yml', 'w') {|f| YAML.dump(config, f)}
loaded = open('store.yml') {|f| YAML.load(f) }
p loaded 
# => {"name"=>"Akbar", "wallet_value"=>9,  \
#  "bills"=>[5, 1, 1,   2], "rank"=>"Admiral"}
```

Comment: yaml format is slower than json, and json is slower than Marshal see http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/ so use Marshal or json for large objects.

Answer (score 1):

Example: write text_area to a file where text_area is an array of strings.

`File.open('output.txt', 'w') { |f| text_area.each { |line| f << line } }`

Don't forget to do error checking on file operations :)

Answer (score 0):

Afaik.. files contain lines not arrays. When you read the files, the data can then be stored in an array or other data structures. I am anxious to know if there is another way.

Comment: You can serialize data structures, save them to a file and them load them back up later. It's a standard way to do light-weight quasi-databases for simple things. Also, I would say that "lines" is already a relatively high level of abstraction for what files hold - it's a human-centric, text-centric way of viewing it. But that's being nit-picky.