# How to save an array of objects into a file in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, class, object

I have an array of objects, where the objects are instances of a class. I would like to save this array into a file in such format that I could read the file back to an array and the objects and its' instance variable values would be as they were before saving. Does someone know how this could be achieved?

The class instance objects that I would like to save to a file are fairly complex containing tens of instance variables that are often other class instance variables themselves.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308393/how-to-store-a-ruby-array-into-a-file) post I tried the following:

TRIAL1:

Save file:

```
require 'pp'
$stdout = File.open('path/to/file.txt', 'w')
pp myArray
```

Load file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
buffer = File.open('path/to/file.txt', 'r').read
myArray = JSON.parse(buffer)
```

but I got a JSON::ParserError

TRIAL2:

Save file

```
serialized_array = Marshal.dump(myArray)
File.open('./myArray.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write(serialized_array) }
```

received Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Comment: When I with the array created as `myArray = ["a", 1, {}]` your TRAIL2 runs fine here.

Comment: TRIAL1: Try writing the array like`serialized_array = JSON.generate( myArray ); File.open('myArray.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write(serialized_array) }`

Comment: Well, you have to use the same format for writing and reading. It doesn’t matter if it’s JSON, YAML, Marshal or something else as long as it is the same.

Comment: @steenslag I tired your suggestion and no error was returned, but instead my class instance objected are presented with strings in the following way "#<User:0x00007ff718f0e9b8>". Do you think that I can turn them back to my class instance objects containing all the data that they had in their instance varaibles? It doesn't seem that they contain any valuable information anymore...

Comment: If the data is to be read back by a program running the same major Ruby version, a faster and easire alternative is to use `Marshal` instead of `JSON`. From a practically viewpoint, data in JSON are human-readable, but you may have to write a custom serializer for your class. Marshalled data are simply a black box holding the data in a form that Ruby can reconstruct them.

Answer (score 3):

TRIAL1 doesn't work because [`pp`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pp/rdoc/Kernel.html#method-c-pp) "prints arguments in pretty form" and that's not necessarily JSON.

TRIAL2 probably isn't working because [`Marshal`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Marshal.html) produces binary data (not text) and you're not working with your file in binary mode, that could lead to encoding and EOL problems. Besides, `Marshal` isn't a great format for persistence since the format is tied to the version of Ruby you're using.

A modification of TRIAL1 to write JSON is probably the best solution these days:

```
require 'json'
File.open('path/to/file.json', 'w') { |f| JSON.dump(myArray, f) }
```

Comment: I tried what  you suggested. This time no error is returned, but when I read the data back to an array it returns and array of strings where my class instance objects are presented in the following style "#<User:0x00007ff718f0e9b8>". It seems that all the data related to the objects has disappeared.

Comment: That suggests that you're in Rails with ActiveRecord, if so then look at the `#as_json` and `#to_json` methods to serialize your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find a solution that worked!

```
dump = Marshal.dump(myArray)
File.write('./myarray', myArray, mode: 'r+b')
dump = File.read('./myarray')
user = Marshal.restore(dump)
```

Marshall was able to do the trick after changing the encoding to binary mode

Comment: There's a big downside to Marshal: the format is specific to the version of Ruby you're using. So it should be fine for temporary storage but its not good for long term storage.